# Ruby building and returning hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm new to Ruby and am trying some simple exercises to figure out how it works.
Currently I am trying to sort through a string, figure out how many of each letter is in the string then return these values in a hash. Once I get all the values in the hash I want to be able to modify that data with other methods.

```
    require 'pp'

    def countLetters
      #creating variables for processing
      start = "If debugging is the process of removing software bugs, then programming must be the process of putting them in."
      alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
      output = alph.each_char do |i|
        char = alph[i]

        # moving all letters to lower case
        num = start.downcase.count i
        # pass the char and value into a hash
          if num >= 1
          #puts "#{char} = #{num}"
          return [{:letter => char, :value => num}]
        end
      end
    end

    pp countLetters
```

I can get it to return the first value, but I cannot seem to figure out how to iterate on the method to return value 2,3,4 etc until I receive nil. Any help with this would be great. I am solely using pp in this to watch my values returning.

Answer (score 0):

replacing return in line 15 with p seems to print rest of the values.
return is causing it to exit the each_char loop

Comment: I understand this, would a better way to approach this be to build the hash within the loop then return the entire hash? using something like

       hash = Hash.new
       hash.store {input}
       return hash

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I was building the hash incorrectly. Below is how I solved this.

```
    require 'pp'

    def countLetters
      #creating variables for processing
      start = "If debugging is the process of removing software bugs, then programming must be the process of putting them in."
      alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
      output = Hash.new
      alph.each_char do |i|
        char = alph[i]
        # moving all letters to lower case
        num = start.downcase.count i
        # pass the char and value into a hash
        if num >= 1
          #puts "#{char} = #{num}"
          output.store (char) , (num)
        end
      end
      return output
    end

    pp countLetters
```